# Multiple Sessions on Bottle Python

Tags: python, web-applications, wsgi, bottle, beaker

I have built an attendance system for a company based on the Bottle web framework. Working perfectly fine, but it is not allowing multiple sessions. i.e, I want to access the same local host on Firefox, Microsoft Edge, and google chrome at the same time. Can anyone help me in this regard?

I have tried this code for the beaker, but unable to solve my problem

```
 from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

 session_opts = 
     {
      'session.type': 'file',
      'session.cookie_expires': 300,
      'session.data_dir': './data',
      'session.auto': True
      }
```

Comment: How are you deploying your application?

Comment: What webserver are you running your Bottle application in?